# How to add a key to an existing list from JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

I've been playing around with Python for a few months now, but I'm stuck on one issue specially with adding a new key to an existing list

Here's my existing JSON data:

```
{"ID": 384903848394829, "Items": [{"Apples" : 10, "Bananas" : 5, "Orange" : 15}]}
```

Then, I want to add an item to the "Items" list, so then it would look something like this:

```
{"ID": 384903848394829, "Items": [{"Apples" : 10, "Bananas" : 5, "Orange" : 15, "Peach" : 2}]}
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import json

jsonFile = open(file)
jsonLoad = json.load(jsonFile)
fruitToAdd = {"Peach" : 2}

// Not quite sure what to put here

dump = json.dumps(jsonLoad, indent=4)
file.write(dump)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data is really just a Python dict with two keys: *ID* and *Items*. The value of the *Items* is a list which contains only a single element, and that element happens to be another dict.

Adding a key/value pair to a dict "dic" is as easy as saying: `dic[key] = value` But you have to access the dict to change inside the json data.

```
jsonLoad['Items'][0].update(fruitToAdd)
```

should do the trick.  `jsonLoad['Items']` accesses the *Items* value, which is a list.  The `[0]` accesses the first (and only) element in the list, which is the dict you want to modify.  Then  you modify that dict with the `.update()` call. You can use one dict to update another dict.

There are usually many different ways to do something in coding. This is just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach of accomplishing this task. (No hardcoding needed)

```
dictEx = {"ID": 384903848394829, "Items": [{"Apples" : 10, "Bananas" : 5, "Orange" : 15}]}
fruitToAdd = {"Peach" : 2}
fruit,count = list(fruitToAdd.items())[0]
dictEx['Items'][0][fruit] = count
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess what you're looking for is this:

```
jsonLoad['Items'][0]['Peach'] = 2
```

Alternatively, if you want to programmatically add the answer, and you already hardcoded both the fruit name and number you can also do this:

```
fruitName = 'Peach'
fruitNumber = 2
jsonLoad['Items'][0][fruitName] = fruitNumber
```

But if you want to stick to the current fruitToAdd variable, you can do:

```
fruitToAdd = {"Peach" : 2}

fruitKey = list(fruitToAdd.keys())[0]
fruitValue = list(fruitToAdd.values())[0]

jsonLoad['Items'][0][fruitKey] = fruitValue
```

This third method is quite interesting because you are playing around with the dictionary keys and values as a list. Albeit, it is a little too complicated.